# What kind of Exception occurred?

Tags: java, exception

I tried to create a test ClassCastException:

In line 1: it prints out `class cast exception` as I expected
 In line 2: it just prints `exception.RuntimeExceptionTest$1B@7852e922` (RuntimeExceptionTest is my class name). I wonder what kind of exception here?

```
 try {
            class A { }
            class B extends A {}
            class C extends A {}
            A objA = new B();
            System.out.println((C)objA); // Line 1
            System.out.println((A)objA); // Line 2
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Line 2 didn't throw an exception at all. What you're seeing is the toString of that objA. It looks like that because the class has a generated name, since you're declaring the class within a method. (That's a fairly rarely used language feature, btw.)

Comment: Please show the actual class names in your code so that it matches with the given output.

Comment: I saw my stupid question @@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line2 doesn't throw an exception. From the Oracle javadocs:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

That means your Line2 just prints what *objA.toString()* returns, which is

```
 exception.RuntimeExceptionTest$1B@7852e922
```

since *exception.RuntimeExceptionTest* is your class name.